# Limit Mat image in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-recognition, mat, opencv3.0

im introducing in OpenCV. Im trying to recognise several parts from face (eyes and mouth). My software recognise correctly face and eyes but i have some issues with the mouth. It shows me several mouths in top place from the face, i realised that in the down place from the face it show the mouth and i need limiting the image from face to take only the mouth.

I hace the next code:

```
Mat faceRoi = frame_gray(faces[i]);

    vector<Rect> eyes;
    eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale(faceRoi, eyes);

    cout << "NUMERO EYES: " << eyes.size() << endl;

    for(unsigned int j=0; j<eyes.size(); j++)
    {
        Point center( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width * 0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height * 0.5);
        int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height) * 0.3 );
        circle(frame, center, radius, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 3, 8, 0 );       
    }

    cout << " FACE-ROI ---->    ROWS: " << faceRoi.rows << "  COLS: " << faceRoi.cols << endl;

    vector<Rect> smiles;

    smile_cascade.detectMultiScale(smileRoi, smiles);
    cout << "NUMERO SMILES: " << smiles.size() << endl; 
    for(unsigned int k=0; k<smiles.size(); k++)
    {
        Point center(faces[i].x + smiles[k].x + smiles[k].width * 0.5, faces[i].y + smiles[k].y + smiles[k].height * 0.5);
        ellipse(frame, center, Size(smiles[k].width * 0.5, smiles[k].height * 0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar(0,255,255), 3, 8, 0);
    }
```

My question is the next... how exactly I can copy the image from in another one with new limits (range, I only want the middle or 2/3 part from that image, the place from the mouth).

Hope anyone can help me!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can define smallRoi like following code (reference : [smiledetect.cpp](https://github.com/sturkmen72/opencv/blob/patch-2/samples/cpp/smiledetect.cpp#L206-L210))

```
vector<Rect> smiles;

// insert this lines to your code    
Rect r = faces[i];
const int half_height=cvRound((float)r.height/2);
r.y=r.y + half_height;
r.height = half_height-1;
smileRoi = frame_gray( r );

smile_cascade.detectMultiScale(smileRoi, smiles);
```